# Get value of selected item in jquery mobile listview

Tags: php, mysql, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a php web page which contains a jquery mobile listview which is populated by a mySQL database.
What I am trying to do is as follows: When the user clicks on a item within the listview, he/she is brought to a webpage which shows the records for only that selected Item in a table.

My main problem is trying to find the value of the selected item from the previous page.

My code is as follows:
Connected to the dB

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$name     = $row['column'];
}
```

Comment: DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/994/ this  may help you else be precise in your question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/1184/ updated fiddle